# How do I remove HTML that I place dynamically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

lets say i have fallowing html...

```
<li><a href="#" id='DataSheets' >Data Sheets</a><font class="leftNavHitsFont">- (1)</font></li>
<li><a href="#" id='ApplicationNotes' >Application Notes</a><fontclass="leftNavHitsFont">- (6)</font></li>
```

what i want to do is, add a html on onclick of these links, if you click on first link output should look like

```
<li><span>ajksdfskaj</span></li>  
<li><a href="#" id='ApplicationNotes' >Application Notes</a><fontclass="leftNavHitsFont">- (6)</font></li>
```

means hide the original html of that li and append new html for ex. a span as i have written above...and if i clicked on second link the first li should get it's original html and appended html should get removed and get appended to current li bieng clicked..in this case output should look like...

```
<li><a href="#" id='DataSheets' >Data Sheets</a><font class="leftNavHitsFont">- (1)</font></li>
<li><span>ajksdfskaj</span></li>
```

i tried to achieve this thing through variuos way...but could not find out the correct way..
please help me out guys..
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: I believe that [the `font` tag is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('li > a').live('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings('li').find('a, font').show().end().find('span').remove();
    $(this).parent().append('<span>ajksdfskaj</span>').find('a, font').hide();
});
```

I used `.live()` because it seems like you're adding the `<a>` dynamically, though if that's not the case, `.click()` will suffice.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VewSL/1/

Comment: but when i clicked on onother link then i think this will neither remove the appended html from previous link nor retrieve the original html of previous link.

Comment: i have already called a function on onclick of link for other stuffs..i have to write this code inside that function..

Comment: @Vivek, sorry I didn't realise that requirement. Modified my code to suit. Also, you may attach as many click handlers as necessary, you don't have to use the existing function.

Comment: yup that's true.it seems like this should do the trick..let me check

Comment: this line var lis = $('li'); can be written in this way lis = $('div#finalTree li'); ???

Comment: thanks buddy...it's working but the problem is..if i keep clciking on links span getting appended as many times i have clicked

Comment: @Vivek, not sure what you mean. How can you click on the links more than once since they get hidden? See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/VewSL/1/

Comment: actually these lis are inside div...so while appending the html,variable containing html should reinitialised after appending html, bcoz of this i was getting that problem..any way i solved that...and you solved my actual problem...thanks a lot dude..

Answer (score 0):

to build upon Box9's code:

```
var prevClickedLink = null;
var prevHTML = null;

$('a').live('click', function(){
 if( prevClickedLink ){
  //restore the previous html
  prevClickedLink.html(prevHTML);
 }

 prevClickedLink = $(this).parent();
 prevHTML = prevClickedLink.html();

 prevClickedLink.empty().append('<span>blabla</span>');
});

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">tekst goes here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tekst goes here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tekst goes here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tekst goes here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tekst goes here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tekst goes here</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following..

```
$(document).ready(OnDocumentReady);
```

var g_sInnerHTML = "ajksdfskaj"
var g_sPrevInnerHTML_li = "";
var g_oPrevLi = null;

function OnDocumentReady()
{
  $('li').click(On_Li_Click);
}

function On_Li_Click()
{
    if(g_oPrevLi != null && 
       g_oPrevLi != undefined &&
       g_sPrevInnerHTML_li != "")
    {
      // Reset the text of previous "li"..
      $(g_oPrevLi).html(g_sPrevInnerHTML_li);
    }
    g_sPrevInnerHTML_li = $(this).html();
    g_oPrevLi = $(this);
    $(this).html(g_sInnerHTML);
}

Comment: thanks buddy, but i got the solution in much simpler and shorter way:)